# How to validate an integer in Asp.net to fall into multiple intervals with built-in validation (or a range with exception)?

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-validation

I have an integer that can fall in range from -1000 to 1000 but cannot be zero. I cannot find any built-in validation that can fix this:

- Range can be only used once and does not allow exceptions or intervals
- Required does not allow zero validation

I know I can just write a custom attribute, but was wondering if I can achieve this in a simple way that I cannot find.

And ideally not regular expression, though I guess that would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exclude the value from a range. Using ranges is as simple as that (but it DOESN'T support any excluding):

```cs
[Range(-1000, 1000)]
public int Amount {get; set;}
```

But you can easily achieve it writing validation using [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)